# Is there an official MRSS xsd?

Tags: java, xml, rss, xsd, yahoo

I am trying to validate mrss feeds against an official mrss xsd, maybe from yahoo, but couldn't find one. I have been using one from http://yarfraw.sourceforge.net/xsd/extension/mrss.xsd but I am not sure how reliable this is. the **javax.xml.validation** package throws this exception when I use the above xsd: 
the line that throws the exception: 
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("path to mrss.xsd"));

Exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'dcterms:valid' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Dublin Core it's looking for. You should be able to use http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd to resolve that name.