# How to fix my RSS feed when given the parsing error?

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I am using the RSS feed (wordpress site) with mailchimp to send out new post notifications. the feed was working last week and we have been sending out notifications. 
I tried to send out a notification today, and it didnt send. so i went into mailchimp and it said that RSS feed was invalid.

[RSS feed for my website](http://simplyjc.com/feed)

I ran it through a feed validator and it gave me this:

---

[ImageREAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft5L5.png)

---

Run it through a validator to see full readout.
Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd include your input RSS and the error your XML parser is giving you.

Comment: I am completely new to this, for host gator they just ask for the url of the rss feed (which is linked above) and the picture above is the XML parser I believe.

Comment: All I can say is that mailchimp complains about the use of CSS-like values `100%` and `auto` when Media RSS `width` and `height` attributes expect plain numeric values such `300` and `400` instead. At least this is what I gleaned from their [best practice guide](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#best-practices) since [there is no formal XML schema for Media RSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509876/is-there-an-official-mrss-xsd#14565915). Sorry but I'm no expert in WP and can't tell you how to make WP not populate the `width` and `height` values.

Comment: @imhotap Thank you for your help